# Device::HID read barcode scanner convert binary to Ascii

Tags: perl, barcode-scanner, hid

I try to read barcode form scanner. I had got data from scanner and the format is binary. How do I conert binary to Ascii string?

The barcode type is code 39.

A1234 =>  [Barcode SCANNRT] => [perl] => binary => ?? A1234 ???

```
use Device::HID;
use Data::Hexdumper qw(hexdump);

my $dev = Device::HID->new(vendor => 0x04b4, product => 0x0100) or die "No such device !\n";
$dev->timeout = 0.1; # seconds (=100 ms)
my $buf;
my $len=128;

while(defined(my $in = $dev->read_data($buf, $len))){

    if ($in == 0) {
        next;
    }

    print hexdump(
        data           => $buf, # what to dump
        suppress_warnings => false,
        space_as_space=> true,
    );


}
```

The input "A1234" binary output. How to convert to sting "A1234".

```
  0x0000 : 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 1E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 1F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : .. .............
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ..!.............
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ..(.............
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
```

I change code to get hexadecimal for each package.

```
use Device::HID;
use Data::Hexdumper qw(hexdump);
my $dev = Device::HID->new(vendor => 0x04b4, product => 0x0100) or die "No such device !\n";
$dev->timeout = 0.1; # seconds (=100 ms)
my $buf;
my $len=128;
my $i=0;

while(defined(my $in = $dev->read_data($buf, $len))){
    if ($in == 0) {
        next;
    }
    $i++;
    my $hex = unpack(  'H*', $buf );
    print sprintf("%02d",$i)." => $hex\n";
}
```

The out is hexadecimal. I change code to output hexadecimal. I received 12 package. 
How to convert to string 'A1234' ?

```
01 => 0200040000000000
02 => 0000000000000000
03 => 00001e0000000000
04 => 0000000000000000
05 => 00001f0000000000
06 => 0000000000000000
07 => 0000200000000000
08 => 0000000000000000
09 => 0000210000000000
10 => 0000000000000000
11 => 0000280000000000
12 => 0000000000000000
```

Comment: I think this would be impossible to answer without knowing what format the binary data is in.

Comment: Thanks your  information ! My barcode type is 'code 93' I will investigate about code format.

Comment: I think you'd probably need to investigate the hardware first

Comment: I change code to get hexadecimal for each package. I found some behavior . 'A1234'  => 02000400 00001e00 00001f00 00002000 00002100 . How do I go next??

Comment: This is a fairly typical USB keyboard data flow. In a nutshell, the 02 is a keyboard modifier code that means the Shift key is pressed and 04 means the "a" key is pressed...giving upper case A. Similarly, 1e means the 1 key is pressed. The all-zero packets mean that no keys are currently pressed.

Comment: @aja ah, that makes more sense - whenever I've used USB barcode scanners myself, they've always been treated like a keyboard by the OS

Answer (score 1):

Split into 8 byte chunks (for your device, it depends on the device descriptor). Column 0 is control key (2nd bit indicates the shift key is pressed), column 2 is the usage code as per section 10 (page 53) of the USB HID Usage Tables doc:

https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf

If the key is a 0, then just ignore it.

So this input:

```
  0x0000 : 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 1E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
  0x0000 : 00 00 1F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
```

becomes:

```
02 04 (shift + a) = "A"
00 00 (ignore)
00 1E (1)         = "1"
00 00 (ignore)
00 00 (ignore)
00 00 (ignore)
00 1F (2)         = "2"
00 00 (ignore)
```

...and so on.